# cant cast application to another package in android studio

Tags: android

AndroidLauncher.java

```
package com.mygdx.game.android;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureAtlas;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;

public class AndroidLauncher extends ApplicationAdapter {



private SpriteBatch batch;
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation animation;
private  float Time=0;


@Override
public void create() {
    batch=new SpriteBatch();
    atlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("JAGUAR.atlas"));
    animation=new        com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Animation(1/30f,atlas.getRegions());


}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
}

@Override
public void render() {
    batch.begin();
    Time+=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(Time, true), 300, 500);
    batch.end();
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mygdx.game.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:name="AndroidLauncher"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

LOGCAT IS SHOWING

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher cannot be cast to android.app.Application
```

i m a beginner i dont know how to solve this error. i was just trying to run a simple animation by using a sprite.
 i have seen many answers regarding my problem but i was not able to understand that where i have to put application name in manifest.xml and what is my package name and what i have to write in android manifest.xml after application tag.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AndroidLauncher` needs to extend from `android.app.Application` and the part of your activity is false too. An Activity must extend from Activity.

I don't think that your `ApplicationAdapter` is of type `Application`.

Comment: its ok but it is saying that android launcher cant extend multiple classes when i try to extend activity and i cant remove extension of ApplicationAdapter because create(),render()and dispose() methods will not be valid if i do that...